# Printing only the value of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python

I would like further explanation as to why the following code prints the value of the key.  I am learning Python for a class and Zybooks is terrible at explaining.

```
# Complete the function to return a dictionary value
# if it exists or return Not Found if it doesn't exist
def findDictItem(mydict, key):
# Student code goes here
    if key in mydict:
        return (mydict[key])
    else:
        return 'Not Found'
# expected output: yellow
print(findDictItem({'tomato': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow', 'lime': 'green'} , 'banana'))
# expected output: Not Found
print(findDictItem({'Brazil': 'Brasilia', 'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Indonesia': 'Jakarta'},'Cameroon'))
```

The `return(mydict[key])`, in my understanding, should return the key not the value, but returns they value instead.

Would someone please provide clarity?

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual dictionary.  Also if you want to return the key, why not `return key`.  `mydict[key]` should return the value for that key.

Comment: "the return(mydict[key]) in my understanding should return the key not the value" - what? No. If you want to return the key, you'd just `return key`. The dict wouldn't be involved at all. `mydict[key]` retrieves the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a dictionary is a map of keys to values, like

```py
{
   'Ireland':   'Dublin',
   'Indonesia': 'Jakarta'
#   ^key         ^value
}
```

`mydict[key]` returns the value of the dictionary at index `key`. If you want the value of the dict at a certain key, you would use `mydict[key]`, so `mydict['Ireland']` will return `Dublin`.

If you just want to return `Dublin`, you would use `return key`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I was confused as to the process but it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print only the key or value, you can use something like this.

```
a = {'tomato': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow', 'lime': 'green'}
for key,value in a:
    print (key) #will print keys : tomato, banana, lime
    print (value) #will print values : red, yellow, green
    print (a[key]) #will print values : red, yellow, green
```

If you want keys, just change your code to say

```
if key in mydict:
    return key
else:
    return 'Not Found'
```

Also, you can simplify the code further.

```
return (key) if key in mydict else 'Not Found'
```

I rewrote your code as follows:

```
def findDictItem(mydict, key):
# Student code goes here
    return key if key in mydict else 'Not Found'
# expected output: yellow
print(findDictItem({'tomato': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow', 'lime': 'green'} , 'banana'))
# expected output: Not Found
print(findDictItem({'Brazil': 'Brasilia', 'Ireland': 'Dublin', 'Indonesia': 'Jakarta'},'Cameroon'))
```

Output:

```
banana
Not Found
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I like the way you simplified it. I didnt think to add the if else statements on the return line.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make an example, there is the dictionary function [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which returns a default value if the key isn't in the dictionary.

```
# Complete the function to return a dictionary value
# if it exists or return Not Found if it doesn't exist

def findDictItem(mydict, key):
    return mydict.get(key, 'Not found')
```

Comment: This is very useful,  I tried to use the .get() a few times but didnt have the correct syntax.